# Django - How to make an optional field required based on request

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I want to be able to save a form as a draft when it's not completely filled up and also save it as usual with classic django form validation.

To do so, I have two submit buttons in my form and I find out in my post request which button has been clicked :

```
class MyView(UpdateView):
     def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        def submit_draft(self, request):
                if 'draft' in request.POST:
                    out = True
                else:
                    out = False
                return out
```

In my models, all my field allow blank fields so saving an incomplete form as *draft* causes no issue if fields are empty.

I would like to make the form fields required when the form is saved with the normal *save* action.

One option I have thought of so far but didn't successfully implement :

=> Override *get_form* function so that when I hit *Save as draft* it just does it's normal action and when I hit *Save*, it modifies my fields required attribute.

**tldr:** I'm looking for a way to do something like that to my form based on the submit button that's been clicked

```
for field in form:    
        self.fields[field].required = True
```

Comment: I just thought of sublassing the form class to have two versions, with and without required fields. I could then call the right form depending on if I *save* or *save as draft*. Would that be an acceptable alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my problem by subclassing my forms as follows :

*My form based on my model with null and blank = True*

```
class RegionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Region
        fields = ['region_name',
                  'region_description'
                  ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].required = True

class RegionDraftForm(RegionForm):
    class Meta(RegionForm.Meta):
        pass

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegionDraftForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].required = False
```

That way I can instantiate in my views the form I need to save as draft or to normally save with complete form validation.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I have used in the past is to serialise the content of the form into a "drafts" table when the "save draft" button is clicked.

When a user comes back to editing the form you load the json back into the form for continued editing. This can be done either using javascript or within the django form view.

Some steps you might follow:

1. When "Save Draft" is clicked, post the form to the draft view.
2. Serialise the content into json; storing the content in a "drafts model".
3. When a user click to re-open a draft pull the content from the database, parsing the json back into the form.
4. When the user clicks "Save" you save the form contents into the database and delete the draft from the "drafts table".

This is an example of what your `Drafts` model could look like.

```
class Drafts(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    form_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    serialised_form = models.TextField() # could use json field here

    def to_dict(self):
        return json.loads(self.serialised_form)
```

I see this method having a number of advantages over

Comment: That's a good idea. I'd still try to do it by overriding some of my forms methods because my form has multiple inline formsets and I'd like to do it for all my formsets too.